# Null pointer while accessing webdriver from different Step definition class

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to access launch static Webdriver instance in a different step definition class using a static method which has been defined in base class. While accessing it from different class it is giving nullpointer please help to solve this error

Here is my feature file [image: Here is my Feature file]

Here is my base class setup

[image: Base class setup]

Here is my Common step definition where method to invoke Webdriver instance is being called

[image]

Here is the second step definition class[image]

Here is the console logs

[image]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 20 in your stack trace suggests that read.getBrowserName() is returning null. Try swapping the arguments to equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: Yeah Problem is solved now I had given wrong path of properties file and wrong file name for properties file due to which the read.getBrowsername() was returning null

Answer (score -3):

Null point exception happening when is your driver instance are mismatch in class level
if you create driver instance as global variable this problem will resolve

```
static WebDriver driver;
```

insted of this line `protected static webdriver driver =null; use above line`

Comment: This is incorrect. The stack trace suggests the problem is what I described.

Comment: Exactly @AslakHellesøy your solution was correct, If I use the above solution then I face error that webdriver is not accessible in other classes of other packages as it makes the webdriver have default access. So I debugged and found that getbrowsername() was null which was due to wrong path of properties file. I corrected it and now it is running fine. Thanks for your help.